# Microsoft Graph Proxy and Bypass SSL

Tags: java-8, microsoft-graph-api

Im using the below :
Java 8
microsoft-graph : 2.10.0
microsoft-graph-auth : 0.2.0
okhttp : 3.14.9

I want to fetch data from Intune using Microsoft Graph API, want to use proxy and also bypass SSL (for testing). As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=java), i have used the OKHttpClient. Used the OkHttpClient for configuring the proxy, sslSocketFactory and hostnameVerifier but it is no working.

```
final ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(this.clientId, this.scopes, this.clientSecret, this.tenantId, NationalCloud.Global);

final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0] {};
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
            }
        } };

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

final OkHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(new ICoreAuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticateRequest(final Request request) {
                return request;
            }
        }).newBuilder().proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(this.proxyHost, this.proxyPort)))
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(final String arg0, final SSLSession arg1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).build();     

final IHttpProvider httpProvider = DefaultClientConfig.createWithAuthenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .getHttpProvider(httpClient);

final IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .httpProvider(httpProvider).buildClient();

IUserCollectionPage page = graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();
```

I get the below errors:

```
org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider.getAccessTokenNewRequest(ClientCredentialProvider.java:102)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider.getAcccessToken(ClientCredentialProvider.java:67)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider.authenticateRequest(ClientCredentialProvider.java:49)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:395)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:220)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseCollectionRequest.send(BaseCollectionRequest.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.UserCollectionRequest.get(UserCollectionRequest.java:72)
    at com.hsbc.gme.test.graph_test.App.main(App.java:114)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.setRequestBody(URLConnectionClient.java:124)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:91)
    ... 12 more
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220401 : Unauthorized
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[...]
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
Mar 14, 2021 11:30:17 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


401 : Unauthorized
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


401 : Unauthorized
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromConnection(GraphServiceException.java:496)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:503)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:423)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:220)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseCollectionRequest.send(BaseCollectionRequest.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.UserCollectionRequest.get(UserCollectionRequest.java:72)
    at com.hsbc.gme.test.graph_test.App.main(App.java:114)
```

**Note : If i use https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort then the proxy works, however how can i make it working with the OkHttpClient. Also need a way to bypass SSL**

Comment: AFAIK, if you're using OkHTTPClient, they need to have a bypass SSL as well

Comment: I have included the bypass SSL with OkHTTPClient as seen in the code above.